# cancel transaction in MultiBit Classic

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, multibit, multibit-hd, private-key-import

I'm trying to send some BTC - I have two send transactions stuck in MultiBit Classic (0.5.19). They have been stuck for a few weeks.

Both transactions have fee of 0.0001 BTC fee which is most likely why they are stuck.

I tried 'resetting the blockchain' several times in the last couple of days, and I tried increasing the fee to 0.0005 BTC between resets, all to no avail. The transactions still show up as having a 0.0001 BTC fee.

What can I do get these transactions processed (or cancelled)?

The documentation for MultiBit HD, the new version of Multibit, states that the best way to upgrade from MultiBit Classic is to create a new wallet and transfer the balance but how can I do this if the bitcoin is stuck in the transaction?

If I was to export the private keys to another wallet service, say  blockchain.info, what would happen to the BTC in the stuck transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Control over money in Bitcoin is defacto<sup>[1]</sup> binary: either a transaction has been confirmed in a block and the money has been signed over, or the sender remains in control of the money. Hence, when you export the keys from MultiBit and import them to another wallet, you will be able to overwrite your previous transaction by issuing another transaction transferring the money somewhere else (unless the new platform is aware of your previous transaction and forbids doublespends).

---

<sup>[1]</sup>The only exception to this is the option of the recipient to create a child-pays-for-parent transaction which provides a sufficient aditional transaction fees to compensate the low fee of its parent. Still the money is only signed over once the transaction is in confirmed in a block though.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. I am very much in the same boat as OP. Still wondering what to do. I am using MultiBit Classic 0.5.17 and have three transactions stuck for days now with no hope of moving. My version of MultiBit automatically adds 0.0001BTC as transaction fee to any transfer and there is no way to adjust that. This makes double-spending with higher fee impossible. What to do?!

Comment: @VladimirFerdman: Please see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/54447/5406 for other software that can import Multibit wallets. I can also not stress enough that you shouldn't be using 3.5 year old wallet software in a fast moving space like Bitcoin.

Comment: Thank you for attempting to answer the question, but the the link provided talks about MultiBit HD, not classic. I am trying to migrate away from a 3 year old software, but it is proving more difficult than it should be. I can not move my bitcoin from the wallet created by another software and I can't spend the coin to another wallet of mine because the old software does not provide a way to adjust transaction fees. Do you see the problem?